# Are there any instances in scriptures of husband & wife separated AND remarried, because of reasons accepted by shastras?

Tags: scripture, marriage, divorce

In this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16738/remarriage-in-san%c4%81tana-dharma) about remarriage, the reasons for a husband leaving a wife, or a wife leaving a husband, are listed.

Are there any actual examples in Smriti of this happening - where husband remarried or wife remarried ? I'm not just asking about sanyasa or remaining separate throughout, or marrying younger brother, or sister (non-family relations only)
I'm asking example from **Itihasa & Purana**.

Just to take couple examples from Manu Smriti - a husband superseding (taking another wife not divorce) a 'quarrelsome/disobedient' (apriyavadini) wife, or a wife waiting in vain for several years for a husband who went abroad and then remarrying another unrelated (not brother) man ?

Again, I want examples that are similar to what's happening nowadays after divorce.. man marrying an unrelated woman, or woman marrying an unrelated man.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did Rāmānuja abandon his wife? If yes, on what grounds?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22152/did-r%c4%81m%c4%81nuja-abandon-his-wife-if-yes-on-what-grounds)

Comment: @RakeshJoshi and others who voted to close this as duplicate - i'm asking reference from Itihasa & Puranas

Comment: yes you cant get reference from vedas or yoga sutras. I also asked the shastric grounds which permit such separation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why didn't Lord Ram try to prove Mother Sita's Purity but rather chose to exile her?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20050/why-didnt-lord-ram-try-to-prove-mother-sitas-purity-but-rather-chose-to-exile)

Comment: @iammilind, no i'm asking about example where husband or wife remarried

Comment: Kaikeyi's mother was abondoned. I heard this. Please try to find reference yourself.

Comment: ur q is unclear...if husband has disappeared/dead, woman allowed to remmarry as per scriptures and we hv example Tara, Mandodari...as per scriptures first marrying in own varana man could marry in lower varnas without taking even divorce...Are Gautama, Jamdagni, Durvasa etc not examples for apriyavadini wife case...also Ganga & Santanu example should fit in some category...if you can clarify which category actually u r looking for it would be more clear...

Comment: Tara/Mandodari did not marry unrelated people, but the younger brother. Gautama did not remarry another woman, neither did Jamadagni. IDK about durv. Ganga is a apsara devi come down due to curse, same Shantanu. I'm asking about regular men/women

Comment: There is a story of Nala and Damayanti in the MBH where Nala abandons Damayanti. Later Damayanti holds a swayamvara and it is attended by the kings of that age. This is not an answer because Nala attends the swayamvara and they get back together. However it doesn't seem to be frowned upon.

Comment: Scriptures say she should marry husband's younger brother and if younger brother is not there then someone else https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28422/12304 so how those examples are invalid??

Comment: @YDS, i'm not saying they are invalid according to shastras.. i'm specifically asking for examples where someone married OTHER than younger brother or sister.

Comment: It is clear to me that @ram is asking whether there is any instance of a husband and wife getting divorced and remarrying another unrelated womand or man respectively. And he is asking for examples from itihasas and puranas. It is a valid  question and I voted to leave it open. That said, may be a rewording of the question might help?