# What will happen when a man have sex with a non-virgin woman?

Tags: marriage, women, manu-smriti, sex

Having sex with a virgin woman is generally [considered as Gandharva Vivah.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49965/what-is-the-essential-requirement-of-gandharva-wedding-is-penetration-essentia)

But What about non-virgin woman?
Is having sex with non-virgin woman sin ? Is it minor sin (for man) ?

Can a non-virgin woman marry someone else ?

People often cite this verse of manusmriti to tell that non-virgin woman can't marry.
But It is wrong as no where virgin word is used.
The word used is Kanya.
Kanya doesn't mean Virgin.

Manusmṛiti-8.226

> pāṇigrahaṇikā mantrāḥ kanyāsveva pratiṣṭhitāḥ
> nākanyāsu kva cinnṝṇāṃ luptadharmakriyā hi tāḥ

Comment: [Related](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46476/can-a-non-virgin-woman-marry-if-yes-how)