# Is it true that a woman should always follow and worship her husband even if the husband is a bad person?

Tags: marriage, wife, husband

Is it true that a woman should always follow and worship her husband even if the husband is a bad person ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remarriage in Sanātana Dharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16738/remarriage-in-san%c4%81tana-dharma)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. The woman should get rid of her erring husband.

> The five conditions or circumstances under which a woman is permitted
> to marry again are: (1) **the moral degradation of her husband**, (2) his
> death, (3) renunciation by him of all worldly pursuits, (4) his
> resorting to a monastery,  and (5) his impotency. The widow of a man
> can marry the brother of his husband if living and willing to take her
> as his wife, while in the alternative she may marry whomsoever she
> pleases. ………

**Agni Purana 154.5-7**

Comment: Who has spoken these things ? Because traditionally widow remarriage was banned.

Comment: @river https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083384.html